# Array manipulation with multiple conditions – Vue.js / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

In my Vue.js application I use a navigation drawer to display the different pages a user has access to. Pages are also only visible if the administrator has activated the related module. Therefore the unique `moduleID` is set for each page and children. The list is populated by `filteredPages[]`. This array is the result of displaying only the pages a user has access to. All available pages are stored in my original data source `pages[]`.

To sum this up: A page is only shown if **both** of these conditions are **true**:

1. `activatedModules[]` contains the `moduleID` of a page **and** the children.
2. `userPermissions[]` contains the `permissions` value of a children (or page if there is no children).

**My code:**

```
export default {
    data: () => ({
        pages: [
            {
                text: 'Team', moduleID: 'm1',
                children: [
                { text: 'Dashboard', route:'team/dashboard', permissions: 'p101', moduleID: 'm1-1' },
                ],
            },
            {
                text: 'Planner', moduleID: 'm2',
                children: [
                { text: 'Events', route:'/planner/events', permissions: 'p201', moduleID: 'm2-1' },
                { text: 'Calendar', route:'/planner/calendar', permissions: 'p202', moduleID: 'm2-2' },
                ],
            },
            {
                text: 'HR', moduleID: 'm3',
                children: [
                { text: 'Staff', route:'/hr/staff', permissions: 'p301', moduleID: 'm3-1' },
                { text: 'Config', route:'/hr/config', permissions: 'p302', moduleID: 'm3-2' },
                ],
            },
            {
                text: 'Admin', moduleID: 'm4',
                children: [
                { text: 'Users', route:'/admin/users', permissions: 'p401', moduleID: 'm4-1' },
                { text: 'Security', route:'/admin/security', permissions: 'p402', moduleID: 'm4-2' },
                ],
            },
            { text: 'Support', route:'/support', permissions: 'p50', moduleID: 'm5' },
        ],
        activatedModules: ['m1', 'm1-1', 'm3', 'm3-1', 'm3-2' 'm4', 'm4-1', 'm4-2', 'm5'],
        userPermissions: ['p101', 'p301', 'p302', 'p402', 'p50'],
        // This is the source for my navigation drawer:
        filteredPages: []
    }),
    computed: {
        filterArray() {
            // I tried to use filter() but how can I solve the rest?
            this.filteredPages = this.pages.filter(function(item) {
              for (var this.activatedModules in filter) {
                if /* I would assume that I have to write the condition here */
                return false;
              }
              return true;
            })
        }
    }
}
```

For the code above this should be the output:

```
filteredPages: [
                {
                    text: 'Team', moduleID: 'm1',
                    children: [
                        { text: 'Dashboard', route:'team/dashboard', permissions: 'p', moduleID: 'm1-1' },
                    ],
                },
                // Notice that 'm2' is missing here because it is not in activatedModules[]
                {
                    text: 'HR', moduleID: 'm3',
                    children: [
                        { text: 'Staff', route:'/hr/staff', permissions: 'p301', moduleID: 'm3-1' },
                        { text: 'Config', route:'/hr/config', permissions: 'p302', moduleID: 'm3-2' },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    text: 'Admin', moduleID: 'm4',
                    children: [
                        // 'm4-1' is in activatedModules[] but the user doesn't have the permission 'p401' to view this
                        { text: 'Security', route:'/admin/security', permissions: 'p402', moduleID: 'm4-2' },
                    ],
                },
                { text: 'Support', route:'/support', permissions: 'p50', moduleID: 'm5' },
            ]
```

The permissions of a user are stored in Firebase Cloud Firestore like this:

[image: Screenshot of the data model]

Can you help with the filtering of the array?

Comment: Can you add what `filterArray()` should return in this concrete case?

Comment: @trincot I updated the question with the output in this case.

Comment: @tao My Vue.js application is pretty complex and almost finished now. Therefore I probably have some kind of knowledge to at least get the project to this stage. The pages were coded without the permissions before. I have manipulated arrays with `filter()` before however not with this complexity and didn't find resources online that helped me with this problem in a right way.

Comment: Your example has a problem. `p301` is in the permissions, but you comment in the output that it is not. And for `p401` it is the opposite situation. A typo somewhere?

Comment: Actually, I just realized the mistake, and it's a lot sillier than I thought: you mistakenly wrote `created` instead of `computed`. I'll remove my previous comments.

Comment: @trincot Yes, you're right. It's a typo in the question. I fixed it, thanks.

Comment: @tao Thanks for pointing that out. It should've been `created`. My .vue file has more code in it that is in no relation to this topic. While copying and cutting the code to SO I cut the code before also the `created` opening. You probably won't believe this anyway. Let us just stop this discussion please and use our valuable time in a better way. Merry Christmas :)

Comment: Really not sure why you'd say I wouldn't believe something I said I realized before you confirmed it. Put yourself in my shoes and try to help. Before figuring out you replaced `computed` with `created` it looked like you don't understand the basics. The most helpful thing I could have done was to encourage you to go over the basics. In my estimation, trying to use Vue without a basic understanding of JavaScript is, most likely, frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
computed: {
  filteredPages() {
    return this.pages.map(page => ({
      ...page, 
      children: page.children
        // when children is truthy
        ? page.children.filter(
          // filter out those not in `userPermissions`
          child => this.userPermissions.includes(child.permissions)
          // and those not in `activatedModules`
            && this.activatedModules.includes(child.moduleID)
        )
        : page.children
    })).filter(
      // only keep page if in `activatedModules` and...
      page => (this.activatedModules.includes(page.moduleID)) &&
        // if children is truthy and has length or...
        (page.children?.length || (
          // if children is falsy and page.permissions in userPermissions
          !page.children && this.userPermissions.includes(page.permissions)
        ))
    );
  }
}
```

See it working:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    pages: [
      {
        text: 'Team',
        moduleID: 'm1',
        children: [
          { text: 'Dashboard', route:'team/dashboard', permissions: 'p101', moduleID: 'm1-1' }
        ],
      }, {
        text: 'Planner',
        moduleID: 'm2',
        children: [
          { text: 'Events', route:'/planner/events', permissions: 'p201', moduleID: 'm2-1' },
          { text: 'Calendar', route:'/planner/calendar', permissions: 'p202', moduleID: 'm2-2' },
        ],
      }, {
        text: 'HR',
        moduleID: 'm3',
        children: [
          { text: 'Staff', route:'/hr/staff', permissions: 'p301', moduleID: 'm3-1' },
          { text: 'Config', route:'/hr/config', permissions: 'p302', moduleID: 'm3-2' },
        ],
      }, {
        text: 'Admin',
        moduleID: 'm4',
        children: [
          { text: 'Users', route:'/admin/users', permissions: 'p401', moduleID: 'm4-1' },
          { text: 'Security', route:'/admin/security', permissions: 'p402', moduleID: 'm4-2' },
        ],
      },
      { text: 'Support', route:'/support', permissions: 'p50', moduleID: 'm5' }
    ],
    activatedModules: ['m1', 'm1-1', 'm3', 'm3-1', 'm3-2', 'm4', 'm4-1', 'm4-2', 'm5'],
    userPermissions: ['p101', 'p301', 'p302', 'p402', 'p50']
  }),
  computed: {
    filteredPages() {
      return this.pages.map(page => ({
        ...page, 
        children: page.children
          ? page.children.filter(
            child => this.userPermissions.includes(child.permissions)
              && this.activatedModules.includes(child.moduleID)
          )
          : page.children
      })).filter(
        page => (this.activatedModules.includes(page.moduleID))
          && (page.children?.length || (
            !page.children && this.userPermissions.includes(page.permissions)
          ))
      );
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pre v-html="filteredPages" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like the approach. However there also seems to be an issue when `permissions` is completely empty. The user still gets to see the top-level pages (without children) because the code just outputs the top-level pages.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

in the code snippet below I used a filter first to filter by `activatedModules` then used a `forEach` to filter each object `children` property by `userPermissions`, I think you can implement this in your vue component or get an idea about how to tackle the problem (hope this helps):

```js
const pages = [{
    text: 'Team',
    moduleID: 'm1',
    children: [{
      text: 'Dashboard',
      route: 'team/dashboard',
      permissions: 'p1382',
      moduleID: 'm1-1'
    }, ],
  },
  {
    text: 'Planner',
    moduleID: 'm2',
    children: [{
        text: 'Events',
        route: '/planner/events',
        permissions: 'p47289',
        moduleID: 'm2-1'
      },
      {
        text: 'Calendar',
        route: '/planner/calendar',
        permissions: 'p283',
        moduleID: 'm2-2'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    text: 'HR',
    moduleID: 'm3',
    children: [{
        text: 'Staff',
        route: '/hr/staff',
        permissions: 'p34729',
        moduleID: 'm3-1'
      },
      {
        text: 'Config',
        route: '/hr/config',
        permissions: 'p382',
        moduleID: 'm3-2'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    text: 'Admin',
    moduleID: 'm4',
    children: [{
        text: 'Users',
        route: '/admin/users',
        permissions: 'p3z4',
        moduleID: 'm4-1'
      },
      {
        text: 'Security',
        route: '/admin/security',
        permissions: 'p2u3',
        moduleID: 'm4-2'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    text: 'Support',
    route: '/support',
    permissions: 'p332j',
    moduleID: 'm5'
  },
];
const activatedModules = ['m1', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5'];
const userPermissions = ['m1-1', 'm3-1', 'm3-2', 'm4-2'];
// This is the source for my navigation drawer:
let filteredPages = null;

filteredPages = pages.filter(x => activatedModules.includes(x.moduleID));
filteredPages.forEach(x => {
 if (x.children)
  x.children = x.children.filter(y => userPermissions.includes(y.moduleID));
});

console.log(filteredPages);
```

Comment: Same problem as tao's answer:, There seems to be an issue when `permissions` is completely empty. The user still gets to see the top-level pages (without children) because the code just outputs the top-level pages.

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

- You should not be using `function` for callbacks, like you started doing for `filter`, as that will make you lose the right `this` value. Use arrow functions.
- `filter` cannot do the job on its own, as you need to also generate new objects which may have fewer children. So you should first `map` to make those narrowed down objects, and then `filter`.

Without using Vue, you can run the following snippet, which just hard-codes the call to `filterArray`:

```js
let app = {
    computed: {
        filterArray() {
            this.filteredPages = this.pages.map(item => {
                let children = (item.children || []).filter(child => 
                    this.activatedModules.includes(child.moduleID) &&
                    this.userPermissions.includes(child.permissions)
                );
                return (children.length || !item.children) 
                    && this.activatedModules.includes(item.moduleID)
                    && {...item, children};
            }).filter(Boolean);
        }
    },
    data: () => ({
        pages: [
            {
                text: 'Team', moduleID: 'm1',
                children: [
                { text: 'Dashboard', route:'team/dashboard', permissions: 'p101', moduleID: 'm1-1' },
                ],
            },
            {
                text: 'Planner', moduleID: 'm2',
                children: [
                { text: 'Events', route:'/planner/events', permissions: 'p201', moduleID: 'm2-1' },
                { text: 'Calendar', route:'/planner/calendar', permissions: 'p202', moduleID: 'm2-2' },
                ],
            },
            {
                text: 'HR', moduleID: 'm3',
                children: [
                { text: 'Staff', route:'/hr/staff', permissions: 'p301', moduleID: 'm3-1' },
                { text: 'Config', route:'/hr/config', permissions: 'p302', moduleID: 'm3-2' },
                ],
            },
            {
                text: 'Admin', moduleID: 'm4',
                children: [
                { text: 'Users', route:'/admin/users', permissions: 'p401', moduleID: 'm4-1' },
                { text: 'Security', route:'/admin/security', permissions: 'p402', moduleID: 'm4-2' },
                ],
            },
            { text: 'Support', route:'/support', permissions: 'p50', moduleID: 'm5' },
        ],
        activatedModules: ['m1', 'm1-1', 'm3', 'm3-1', 'm3-2', 'm4', 'm4-1', 'm4-2', 'm5'],
        userPermissions: ['p101', 'p301', 'p302', 'p402', 'p50'],
        filteredPages: []
    }),
};

// Demo, simulate Vue's call to computed.filterArray
let data = app.data();
app.computed.filterArray.call(data);
// Verify output:
console.log(data.filteredPages);
```